# How can I read the user roles to authenticate my login C# windows form. Heres my implementation

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi guys I'm really a beginner and need your help and advises.

So I was trying to create authentication in my Login form. The user role is in the same table with username and password but I don't have better idea to achieve authentication in my Winforms.

I want to do something like this
If user role id is == 1
then proceed to admin dashboard
and if user role id is == 2
then proceed to user dashboard

But I'm stuck up in the accessing my database.

So here is my code functions.

This is the LOGIN FUNCTION to the Database:

```
public static bool LOGIN(string user, string pass)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand;
            string Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBPAccounts WHERE username=@user AND passwd=@pass";
            using (var SqlConn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseHelper.connection))
            {

                SqlConn.Open();
                sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, SqlConn);

                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                
                int result = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                return (result > 0);
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}" , ex.Message);
            return false;

        }

    }
```

this is where I want to put if user role is == id  :

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (DatabaseHelper.LOGIN(UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text))
            {
                //dialog box for successful login
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                //to hide the first form when button pressed 
                this.Hide();
                // Log in was successful, do something...
                AdminDashboard admin = new AdminDashboard();
                admin.ShowDialog();

            }
            else
            {
                // Log in was NOT successful, inform the user...
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please can you post your code as text and not images.  It is not possible to copy & paste to debug an image!

Comment: In your database table you should add `TypeofUser` Columns and can have two values the admin or user or 1 or 0.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith sorry sir. already updated it now

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales yes already done that in my table but I dont know how to put it in my button login to check if user role id is 1 or 2.

Comment: Instead of selecting `COUNT(*)`, select the user role from the table. Also, NEVER store passwords in the database, instead store a salted hash.

Answer (score 1):

use sqlDataReader

```
SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    reader.Read();
    if (Convert.ToInt16(reader["TypeofUser"])==1)

    else if Convert.ToInt16(reader["TypeofUser"]==2)

    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I did try your code and put it in my LOGIN Method but the button click msgbox else will be triggered it will prompt me about the msgbox and this.hide still intact

Comment: because LOGIN method can return 
1. Login unsuccessful or
2. Login success and user is regular user or
3. Login success and user is admin user

 change the return value of LOGIN method from bool to integer
which is 0 = login unsuccessful / 1 = login is regular user / 2 = login is admin user

Answer (score -1):

This might help you a bit

```
try{
string query ="SELECT USERNAME,PASSWORD,TYPE from ***** WHERE.....");
conn.Open();
MysqlCommand comm = new MysqlCommand(query,Myconnection);
MysqlDataReader read = comm.ExecuteReader();
if(read.HasRows){
while(read.Read())
   {
    string Type = read.GetString(2);//Get Value of Type
        if(Type.EQuals("admin"))
            {
            //open admin
            }else{ 

          }
   }
}   
else
{
    //Invalid user and pass
}
conn.Close();
}
catch(Exception eee)
{Console.WriteLine(eee.Message);}
```

Comment: Please, never simply swallow exceptions like this.  At the very minimum, log something.  Silently swallowing exceptions will only hinder your ability to find problems in your code.

Comment: Sorry i didn`t notice about my exception  while making this ans but probably he will manage it, anyway ill just edit it

Comment: should i implement this insde my login button or in my login method? sorry but im really confused and got poor logic